# C++ Reading back "incorrect" values from binary file?

Tags: c++, file, input, output

The project I'm working on, as a custom file format consisting of the header of a few different variables, followed by the pixel data. My colleagues have developed a GUI, where processing, writing reading and displaying this type of file format works fine.

But my problem is, while I have assisted in writing the code for writing data to disk, I cannot myself read this kind of file and get satisfactorily values back. I am able to read the first variable back (char array) but not the following value(s).

So the file format matches the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char hxtLabel[8];
    u64 hxtVersion;
    int motorPositions[9];
    int filePrefixLength;
    char filePrefix[100];
..
} HxtBuffer;
```

In the code, I create an object of the above structure and then set these example values:

```
setLabel("MY_LABEL");
setFormatVersion(3);
setMotorPosition( 2109, 5438, 8767, 1234, 1022, 1033, 1044, 1055, 1066);
setFilePrefixLength(7);
setFilePrefix( string("prefix_"));
setDataTimeStamp( string("000000_000000"));
```

My code for opening the file:

```
// Open data file, binary mode, reading
ifstream datFile(aFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!datFile.is_open()) {
    cout  << "readFile() ERROR: Failed to open file " << aFileName << endl;
    return false;
}

// How large is the file?
datFile.seekg(0, datFile.end);
int length =  datFile.tellg();
datFile.seekg(0, datFile.beg);

cout << "readFile() file " << setw(70) << aFileName << " is: " << setw(15) << length  << " long\n";

// Allocate memory for buffer:
char * buffer = new char[length];
// Read data as one block:
datFile.read(buffer, length);
datFile.close();

/// Looking at the start of the buffer, I should be seeing  "MY_LABEL"?

cout << "buffer: " << buffer  << " " << *(buffer)  << endl;

int* mSSX = reinterpret_cast<int*>(*(buffer+8));
int* mSSY = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+9);
int* mSSZ = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+10);
int* mSSROT = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+11);
int* mTimer = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+12);
int* mGALX = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+13);
int* mGALY = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+14);
int* mGALZ = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+15);
int* mGALROT = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+16);
int* filePrefixLength = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer+17);

std::string filePrefix;   std::string dataTimeStamp;

// Read file prefix character by character into stringstream object
std::stringstream ss;
char* cPointer = (char *)(buffer+18);
int k;
for(k = 0; k < *filePrefixLength; k++)
{
    //read string
    char c;
    c = *cPointer;
    ss << c;
    cPointer++;
}
filePrefix = ss.str();

// Read timestamp character by character into stringstream object
std::stringstream timeStampStream;
/// Need not increment cPointer, already pointing @ 1st char of timeStamp
for (int l= 0; l < 13; l++)
{
    char c;
    c = * cPointer;
    timeStampStream << c;
}
dataTimeStamp = timeStampStream.str();

cout << 25 << endl;
cout << " mSSX:   "  << mSSX <<   "  mSSY:   "  << mSSY <<      "  mSSZ: "  << mSSZ;
cout << " mSSROT: "  << mSSROT << "  mTimer: "  << mTimer <<    "  mGALX: "  << mGALX;
cout << " mGALY:  "  << mGALY <<  "  mGALZ:  "  << mGALZ <<     "  mGALROT: "  << mGALROT;
```

Finally, what I see is here below. I added the 25 just to double check that not everything was coming out in hexadecimal. As you can see, I am able to see the label "MY_LABEL" as expected. But the 9 motorPositions all come out looking suspiciously like addresses are not values. The file prefix and the data timestamp (which should be strings, or at least characters), are just empty.

```
buffer: MY_LABEL M
25
 mSSX:   0000000000000003  mSSY:   00000000001BF618  mSSZ: 00000000001BF620 mSSROT: 00000000001BF628  mTimer: 00000000001BF630  mGALX: 00000000001BF638 mGALY:  00000000001BF640  mGALZ:  00000000001BF648  mGALROT: 00000000001BF650filePrefix: dataTimeStamp:
```

I'm sure the solution can't be too complicated, but I reached a stage where I had this just spinning and I cannot  make sense of things.

Many thanks for reading this somewhat long post.

-- Edit--

I might hit the maximum length allowed for a post, but just in case I thought I shall  post the code that generates the data that I'm trying to read back:

```
bool writePixelOutput(string aOutputPixelFileName) {

    // Write pixel histograms out to binary file
    ofstream pixelFile;
    pixelFile.open(aOutputPixelFileName.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);
    if (!pixelFile.is_open()) {
        LOG(gLogConfig, logERROR) << "Failed to open output file " << aOutputPixelFileName;
        return false;
    }

    // Write binary file header

    string label("MY_LABEL");
    pixelFile.write(label.c_str(), label.length());

    pixelFile.write((const char*)&mFormatVersion, sizeof(u64));

    // Include File Prefix/Motor Positions/Data Time Stamp - if format version > 1
    if (mFormatVersion > 1)
    {
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mSSX, sizeof(mSSX));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mSSY, sizeof(mSSY));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mSSZ, sizeof(mSSZ));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mSSROT, sizeof(mSSROT));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mTimer, sizeof(mTimer));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mGALX, sizeof(mGALX));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mGALY, sizeof(mGALY));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mGALZ, sizeof(mGALZ));
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&mGALROT, sizeof(mGALROT));

        // Determine length of mFilePrefix string
        int filePrefixSize = (int)mFilePrefix.size();

        // Write prefix length, followed by prefix itself
        pixelFile.write((const char*)&filePrefixSize, sizeof(filePrefixSize));

        size_t prefixLen = 0;
        if (mFormatVersion == 2)    prefixLen = mFilePrefix.size();
        else                        prefixLen = 100;
        pixelFile.write(mFilePrefix.c_str(), prefixLen);

        pixelFile.write(mDataTimeStamp.c_str(), mDataTimeStamp.size());
    }
    // Continue writing header information that is common to both format versions
    pixelFile.write((const char*)&mRows, sizeof(mRows));
    pixelFile.write((const char*)&mCols, sizeof(mCols));
    pixelFile.write((const char*)&mHistoBins, sizeof(mHistoBins));

    // Write the actual data - taken out for briefy sake
    // ..

    pixelFile.close();

    LOG(gLogConfig, logINFO) << "Written output histogram binary file " << aOutputPixelFileName;

    return true;
}
```

-- Edit 2 (11:32 09/12/2015) --

Thank you for all the help, I'm closer to solving the issue now. Going with the answer from muelleth, I try:

```
/// Read into char buffer
char * buffer = new char[length];
datFile.read(buffer, length);// length determined by ifstream.seekg()

/// Let's try HxtBuffer
HxtBuffer *input = new HxtBuffer;
cout << "sizeof HxtBuffer:  " << sizeof *input << endl;
memcpy(input, buffer, length);
```

I can then display the different struct variables:

```
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER label " << QString::fromStdString(input->hxtLabel);
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER version " << QString::number(input->hxtVersion);
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER hxtPrefixLength " << QString::number(input->filePrefixLength);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    qDebug() << i << QString::number(input->motorPositions[i]);
}
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER filePrefix " << QString::fromStdString(input->filePrefix);
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER dataTimeStamp " << QString::fromStdString(input->dataTimeStamp);
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER nRows " << QString::number(input->nRows);
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER nCols " << QString::number(input->nCols);
qDebug() << "Slice BUFFER nBins " << QString::number(input->nBins);
```

The output is then mostly as expected:

```
Slice BUFFER label  "MY_LABEL" 
Slice BUFFER version  "3" 
Slice BUFFER hxtPrefixLength  "2" 
0 "2109" 
1 "5438" 
...
7 "1055" 
8 "1066" 
Slice BUFFER filePrefix  "-1" 
Slice BUFFER dataTimeStamp  "000000_000000P" 
Slice BUFFER nRows  "20480" 
Slice BUFFER nCols  "256000" 
Slice BUFFER nBins  "0"
```

EXCEPT, `dataTimeStamp`, which is 13 chars long, displays instead 14 chars. The 3 variables that follow: `nRows`, `nCols` and `nBins` are then incorrect. (Should be nRows=80, nCols=80, nBins=1000). My guess is that the bits belonging to the 14th char of `dataTimeStamp` should be read along with `nRows`, and so cascade on to produce the correct `nCols` and `nBins`.

I have separately verified (not shown here) using qDebug that what I'm writing into the file, really are the values I expect, and their individual sizes.

Comment: Hopefully this post is making a bit more sense than my last did.

Comment: Are you forgetting to read the `hxtVersion` variable?  I don't see where you do that.

Comment: @PhilPhil Have you thought if the problem being caused by [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). I haven't reviewed your code, but give it a thought.

Comment: If `mSSX`, `mSSY` and so on are all declared as `int *`, then the `(const char *)&mSSX` you are writing to disk is the address of the variable itself. As you said, the data on disk looks suspiciously like addresses: each one is offset exactly 8 bytes from the previous one, and I'll bet dollars to doughnuts that an `int *` is 8 bytes wide on your platform.

Comment: I also think you have the wrong indirection in your reading code, `int* mSSX = reinterpret_cast<int*>(*(buffer+8));` should be `int* mSSX = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer+8);`

Comment: @PhilPhil, That's because of padding used by the application that saved the data file.  As you know, the ASCII numeric code for 'P' (the one that shows after the end of your 13-character string) is 80 (0x50).  Due to padding, you 13-character array possibly became 14 or 16 bytes long, so that access to integer elements that follow in the structure can be aligned with addresses that match their word length (e.g. if `int` is 4 bytes long, it will always be in a memory position that is a multiple of 4).

Comment: @PhilPhil, You can see that `20480` is actually 0x00005000; since you're probably in a little-endian architetcure, that is one byte 0x00 from the padded `nRows`, and three from the padded `nCols`.  Likewise, the value 1000 (0x000003e8) was shifted three bytes, invading the unpadded `nCols` field as 0x000003e800, that is 256000.  And so on.

Comment: @Paulo1205: You're right, a colleague pointed out the word boundary potentially messing things up - which setting the 13 char array to use 16 sorted out. Thank you everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would try to read exactly the number of bytes your struct is from the file, i.e. something like

```
int length = sizeof(HxtBuffer);
```

and then simply use memcpy to assign a local structure from the read buffer:

```
HxtBuffer input;
memcpy(&input, buffer, length);
```

You can then access your data e.g. like:

```
std::cout << "Data: " << input.hxtLabel << std::endl;
```

Comment: That assumes his native endianness matches the endianness of the file data.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you read to buffer, instead of using the structure for reading?

```
HxtBuffer data;
datFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data), sizeof data);
if(datFile && datFile.gcount()!=sizeof data)
    throw io_exception();

// Can use data.
```

If you want to read to a chracter buffer, than your way of getting the data is just wrong.  You probably want to do something like this.

```
char *buf_offset=buffer+8+sizeof(u64);  // Skip label (8 chars) and version (int64)
int mSSX = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf_offset);
buf_offset+=sizeof(int);
int mSSY = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf_offset);
buf_offset+=sizeof(int);
int mSSZ = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf_offset);
/* etc. */
```

Or, a little better (provided you don't change the contents of the buffer).

```
int *ptr_motors=reinterpret_cast<int *>(buffer+8+sizeof(u64));
int &mSSX = ptr_motors[0];
int &mSSY = ptr_motors[1];
int &mSSZ = ptr_motors[2];
/* etc. */
```

Notice that I don't declare `mSSX`, `mSSY` etc. as pointers.  Your code was printing them as addresses because **you** told the compiler that they were addresses (pointers).

Comment: Be aware of packing if you try to read the struct directly, that int[9] has the potential to upset things.

Comment: @Pete, I know that, and that's why my first suggestion was to read to the struct *and* check the amount of data read.  Besides, the OP was reading to an array of `char`s, and completely messing up with data types and offsets when trying to interpret the data.